# instagram_graph_user_media & instagram_graph_user_profile permissions working only for test users

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

I have an app that displays user's instagram media(like some of the dating apps).

Also, my app has been **reviewed successfully** for permissions - **instagram_graph_user_profile** and **instagram_graph_user_media** and is **in live mode**.

But in the Facebook Developer Console, the **instagram icon is not turning up green**.
Please refer the screenshot.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VnMHLqjTf1oRbvcm2g8Ol80AfB3JqMOg

Flow to display the media is as follows.

**1. My app ask users to authorize using**

> https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=instagram-app-id&redirect_uri=redirect_uri&scope=scope&response_type=code&state=state

**2. Above api responds with a code.Then backend calls -**

> https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
>
> with params - client_id, client_secret, code, grant_type, redirect_uri

**3. Once I receive token from above API, I request long lived token from short-lived token using -**

> https://graph.instagram.com/access_token?grant_type=ig_exchange_token&client_secret=xyz&access_token=abc

**4. Using the long lived token, server requests user info using API -**

> https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=id,username&access_token=abc

**5. Using the same long lived token, server makes request to get user media using API -**

> https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,media_type,media_url,username,caption,timestamp&access_token=abc

This flow works only for **test users**(*Instagram test users who accepted invitation of being a tester in Instagram Developer Platform*).

When non-test user tries to view media, on step 3, I get an error saying -

> {    "error": {
>         "message": "Unsupported get request.",
>         "type": "IGApiException",
>         "code": 100,
>         "fbtrace_id": "A0A24rNXCScki9Ck-8J_55b"    } }

Am I missing something?

This is how I see my Business API Settings.
Please refer the screenshot.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dfdihf20krEcYEmoh8z43_a1T5UQStXr

Under my App review section, I do not see any relevant permission that needs to be reviewed again.

**Edit 1 -**

Note - My app is in beta mode (not yet live on play store).
Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I just went through a similar process getting my app ready for the old API to officially depreciate. I finally found this— hope it helps:
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2219648518091109/

"After your app has been approved, you can get the contract from your Business Manager. You need to do it on a Computer (mobile wont work) and have to be an Admin on the Business.

From your business Manager you just go to Business Info -> Business Contract (https://business.facebook.com/settings/info)